# Disable Equalizer lockscreen UI on (CyanogenMod 12 - Lollipop)

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop

So apparently the Equalizer (or audio) UI component on the lockscreen causes my device to completely become unresponsive to touch from about the middle of the screen down. This started when I got the Lollipop (CyanogenMod 12) OTA update, and I can correlate the behavior to that (restart the device, don't play audio - no issue).

Can I disable that UI component for the lockscreen (or the Equalizer in CM12 if it comes to that) until this is fixed? My device is a OnePlus A0001.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Settings > Lockscreen > Turn off "Display music visualizer"

Comment: Not to be a dick, but if that was an option, I surely would have taken it. There are no options in Display or Lockscreen to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The option to disable it only exists on some of the newer nightly builds. You won't see it on CyanogenOS 12.